# TransactionScope Not catching exceptions

Tags: c#

I've looked at a couple threads, none seem to be helping so here is my TransActionScope code

```
   public void InsertFormData()
    {
        try
        {
            using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
            {
                using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString))
                {
                    cnn.Open();

                    InsertData(cnn);
                    InsertMoreInfo(cnn);
                    //etc...
                    ts.Complete();
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogException(ex);
        }
```

Here is an example of what one of my methods I'm calling there looks like:

```
public void InsertData(cnn)
    {

        SqlCommand cmd = null;
        SqlTransaction trans = null;

        try
        {

            cmd = new SqlCommand("StoredProcedure", cnn, trans);
            trans = cnn.BeginTransaction();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@PARAM1", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd.Parameters["@PARAM1"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@PARAM2", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = RepID;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@PARAM3", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ViolatorID;

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Transaction = trans;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           LogException(ex)
        }
    }
```

I've redone that method a couple different ways with basically the same outcome. I've tried taking the Try/catch out of the method to see if that would trigger an error, but it just triggered my Application_Error in Global.ascx. Basically I just want it to run the methods, if a method doesn't complete correctly it rolls it back.

Comment: Don't call "trans = cnn.BeginTransaction();" and "cmd.Transaction = trans". The SqlConnection should call EnlistTransaction already.

Comment: Thanks, you were indeed correct. I got it working finally :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you eat the exception in the way that you're doing, the execution flow allows your `ts.Complete()` call to run. Either:

- remove the `catch` in `InsertData`,
- make the `catch` in `InsertData` throw again after logging, or
- make `InsertData` return a boolean value to indicate success or failure, and have the calling method only call `ts.Complete()` on success.

Comment: This. But to summarise from a slightly different angle, if you design a function so that the caller cannot tell whether a call succeeded or failed, the caller cannot tell whether a call succeeded or failed *even if you really want to*. Wishful thinking just doesn't work. :)

Comment: I had the try catch returning a bool determine false if it failed, but for whatever reason from what I've been reading on TransactionScope it didn't sound like that was necessarily needed. So basically I need the methods only to run if the method before it returned true? and at the end if success is false dispose of the TransactionScope?

Comment: @Dylan: Right. When the `using` statement ends, if you haven't called `.Complete()`, the transaction will be rolled back automatically.